# Multithread primefactorization using POSIX

Tags: segmentation-fault, return, posix

I need to have a main thread create new threads which each return an array of prime factors of a value passed to them.   For example if a new thread is passed 12 it needs to return an array containing 223 to the main thread.  As my code currently stands I keep getting a segmentation fault.  I am not sure how to return values from a new thread to the main thread. Any help figuring out what is causing the segmentation fault and how to return values back to a main thread?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void *trial_division(void *n);
int main (int argc, char** argv[])
{
while(argc > 0){
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid,NULL,trial_division,argv[argc]);
pthread_join(tid,NULL);
argc--;
}

}//end main
void *trial_division(void *n)
{
printf("I'm a new thread!\n");
int value = atoi(n);
while (value%2 == 0)
{
    printf("%d",2);
    value = value/2;
}
for (int i = 3;i <= sqrt (value); i = i+2)
{
    while (value%i == 0)
    {
            printf("%d",i);
            value = value/i;
    }
}
if (value > 2)
    printf("%d",value);
printf("\n");
}//end trail_division
```

Comment: The segfault is caused by dereferencing argv with argc value. Array indexing starts with zero, so after replacing `argv[argc]` with `argv[argc-1]` there will be no segfault.

Answer (score -1):

Let's first look at the code problems:

- The second argument of `int main(int, char***)` should be `char **`.
- The first string in argv[] is the name of the executable, so you want `while (argc>1) {`.
- With `atoi(n)` you have an *invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘const char*’*, so let's cast this: `atoi( (char*) n)`
- Lastly, you have *no return statement in function returning non-void*. Just `return NULL;`

Now the segmentation fault. It happens because the first thread is created with the argument `argv[argc]`, which cannot exist, since array indices are zero based. So if you change it to `argv[argc-1]`, your code (plus above modifications) will work.

Corrected code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *trial_division(void *n);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    while (argc > 1) {
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, trial_division, argv[argc-1]);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
        argc--;
    }

} //end main
void *trial_division(void *n) {
    printf("I'm a new thread!\n");
    int value = atoi( (char*) n);
    while (value % 2 == 0) {
        printf("%d", 2);
        value = value / 2;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(value); i = i + 2) {
        while (value % i == 0) {
            printf("%d", i);
            value = value / i;
        }
    }
    if (value > 2)
        printf("%d", value);
    printf("\n");

    return NULL;
} //end trail_division
```

Example output:

```
$ ./test 123 45 6789
I'm a new thread!
33173
I'm a new thread!
335
I'm a new thread!
341
```